# How to get list of AWS WAF details

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

I am trying to fetch list of WAF from my AWS account. But always I am getting empty values.

```
AWSWAF client = AWSWAFClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
            .withCredentials(new StaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials)).build();
    ListWebACLsRequest request = new ListWebACLsRequest();
    ListWebACLsResult response = client.listWebACLs(request);
    System.out.println("Response " + response);
    List<WebACLSummary> webACLSummary = response.getWebACLs();
    System.out.println(" webACLSummary "+webACLSummary);
    webACLSummary.forEach(webACL -> {
        System.out.println("Web ACL " + webACL.getName() + " ACLID " + webACL.getWebACLId());
    });
```

Response:

```
Response {WebACLs: []} 
 webACLSummary []
```

But in my AWS Region, I have "AWS WAF", AM I missing anything in my code.

Comment: Does it work if you use the CLI? `aws waf list-web-acls --region us-east-1`

Comment: That I haven't checked, I will check. Thanks

Comment: are you in the right region ? did u create ACL in Cloudfront?